# How to disable horizontal mouse wheel scrolling when mouse is over horizontal scrollbar

Tags: unity, multi-touch, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel, scrollbar

When I'm scrolling around code, I sometimes put my mouse over the horizontal scrollbar and then the mouse wheel scrolls horizontally which is not what I'm used to.

More annoyingly, the two-finger scroll which allows me to scroll vertically or horizontally by moving my fingers up-and-down or left-and-right also changes to scrolling horizontally when going up-and-down if my mouse happens to be over a horizontal scrollbar.

The first problem is my preference but I think the second problem is a bug. How do I change these behaviours?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid with the default window manager, Unity.

Answer (score 0):

May be, using 'xinput' and disable that action buttons.

`xinput list` -> list devices ID
`xinput test <ID>` ->  monitor actions
If you see, that scroll action use mouse buttons 6 and 7.
Disable that buttons.

`xinput set-button-map <ID> 1 2 3 4 5 0 0`

Better solution will be, disable that that scroll action in GUI system, but I don't know that solution. Probably it depend also on specific window manager.